# Android app to block all international calls?

Tags: gratis, android, open-source

I need a free or cheap application that can whitelist only my country and blacklist all other countries.

It's for my mom, she's old, she answers every call and it seems spammers got her number and they keep calling her. I tried blacklisting up to 40 numbers but there's always new numbers to be blocked.

Hence I want to allow her to receive calls from her country only. I want to whitelist my country.

Comment: Depending on your Android version and the device's brand/model, some blacklist functionality might already be present. You can also find a selection of [Call Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97) on my Android site. But I'd say the easiest approach would be having your carrier block them. Can't hurt asking them.

Comment: @Izzy I ended up doing that but even them, they can only block certain countries, they cannot whitelist my country and blacklist everything else

Comment: If there's demand, they'll consider. Imagine 100 people each day wanting that, and they always had to blacklist hundreds of countries without wildcards ;) // Besides, useful hints on our Android sister site: [Can I block calls based on a specific number prefix or pattern?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110470/16575) // [Block all calls from area code unless in Contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172174/16575).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an app called [NoPhone-Spam](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/at.bitfire.nophonespam/) which is free as in speech as well as in beer!

[image]

Here are the feature listed:

> Features:
>
> - Block incoming calls
> - Use special syntax to block countries or providers or parts of numbers
> - Add, update and delete numbers
> - Manage notifications
> - Simple logging of numbers
> - Block calls with suppressed numbers

You can turn blacklist into white list by a simple checkbox and add your country code e.g. `+91*` to white list calls from your country as follows:

[image]

It is licensed under GPLv3+. You can get it from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/at.bitfire.nophonespam/).

Comment: Does it require the phone to be rooted?

Comment: @Lynob No, it doesn't :)

Comment: Awesome, can I download it directly without using F-Droid?